# Drools validation failing with error as "unterminated string literal"

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench, kie-wb

I have defined a rule with following condition.

```
 [ "asmi\"sinternational", "brand1" ] contains msku.brand
```

Validation of this rule is failing with error as

```
Unable to Analyse Expression [ "asmi\"sinternational" ] contains msku.brand: [Error: unterminated string literal] [Near : {... [ "asmi\"sinternational" ] contains msku.brand ....}]
```

Note : Double quote is escaped by "\".

How can I define a list of strings where one string contains double quote as character while defining rule ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to enclose the string in apostrophes and without \-escaping the quotes?

Comment: If you mean 'asmi"sinternational' then yes and it doesnt work. (Internally drools is converting ' to ")